# Here geocoder API: retrieve route number based on coordinates

Tags: rest, here-api

I noticed that I can retrieve route number based on coordinates using geocoding service. If coordinates are located outside the city, instead of street name geocoder returns route number (which is very useful).

Sometimes however route has multiple numbers - eg. "A4/E65/5". Unfortunately geocoder returns only one number - eg. "5". Is there any chance that geocoder can return full number?

Answer (score 0):

Goeocder might not work here, have you tried getLinkinfo ?

e.g

http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&waypoint=45.79728,16.13712&linkattributes=all

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That would be very useful but my client did not buy license for routing service :(

Answer (score 0):

With Geocoding use "locationattributes=addressNames". That will return many name variants including several languages and road numbers, e.g.

```
street: [
  {
    value: "A5",
    language: "de"
  },
  {
    value: "E451",
    language: "de"
  }
]
```